# Visual Studio Code: How debug Python script with arguments

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm using Visual Studio Code in order to debug a Python script.

Following [this guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging), I set up the argument in the `launch.json` file:

[image]

But when I press on *Debug*, it says that my argument is not recognized and Visual Studio Code says:

> error: unrecognized arguments

[image]

As Visual Studio Code is using PowerShell, let's execute the same file with the same argument:

[image]

So: the same file, same path, and same argument. In the terminal it is working, but not in Visual Studio Code.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: None of the solutions below worked for me, even after restarting and spending a hour with this!
Anyone else has some recommendation? This was working a few months ago for me.

Answer (score 319, accepted):

I think the --City and Auckland are used as a single argument. Maybe try separating them like so...

### Single argument

```
"args": ["--city","Auckland"]
```

### Multiple arguments and multiple values

Such as:

```
--key1 value1 value2 --key2 value3 value4
```

Just put them into the `args` list **one by one in sequence**:

```
"args": ["--key1", "value1", "value2", "--key2", "value3", "value4"]
```

Comment: What if I have several arguments, like `--city Auckland --year 2000`?

Comment: Then you do it like "args: ["--city", "Auckland", "--year", "2000"]

Comment: Did someone get nargs to run?
`args: ["--my-n-args", "4 5"]` does not work:
`error: argument -m/--my-n-args: invalid int value: '4 5'`

Edit: Found it myself: `args: ["--my-n-args", "4", "5"]`

Comment: How can I do the same if I do not have any key? I would like to run something like my_program.py train. How can I add the argument "train" that is without any key?

Comment: @konstantin that would be `args: ["train"]` Arguments are just passed to your program by the shell as an array of strings, and here you are defining an array of strings in json format. The Python sys module presents these as a list of strings.

Comment: Great but may I suggest you edit and add the info contained in the solution below?

Comment: what you(pawan) wrote about re key and value is a bit strange to me,  'cos arguments on a command line aren't key value pairs.  To say what niid makes sense  and is simple, just breaking them on spaces.   `"args": ["arg1", "arg2", "arg3", "arg4", "arg5", "arg6"]`  . e.g. ["1","-a","3" ,"--blah","44"]  for arguments of 1 -a 3 --blah 44.

Comment: A note I find useful: for required non-optional positional arguments, you don't need to pass the parameter's name.

Comment: Further to oli-ver's comment above, I couldn't get a list of arg values to work until I added the `nargs` arg to `argparse.ArgumentParser.add_argument()`

Answer (score 128):

I also noticed that if you run the script by clicking on the debug button that looks like this
[image], then the arguments are not passed. However, using `Run -> Start Debugging` (or its shortcut `F5`) passed the arguments successfully.

Comment: Me too, I was using Python: Run Python File in Terminal the whole time...

Comment: @Sourya Dey

Is there any workaround to fix that and make it get the arguments from the Debug button?

Comment: @EdsonManoel: Not that I know of. But you can press the Debug button on the left sidebar to make the Debug pane show on the left. You can then click on the green |> button (which usually says "Python: Current File"), and the script will run in debug mode with arguments.

Comment: 2023 and this bug is still there.

Comment: I've spent the last 30 minutes banging my head against the wall wondering why pressing that button in the upper right wasn't reading my script's arguments. Arg indeed!

Comment: gnnaaah this is so stupid!!

Comment: For seekers, the issue and resolution is here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/18199

Answer (score 37):

[image]

If clicking the "Debug python file" doesn't pass the arguments then add `"purpose": ["debug-in-terminal"]` in the `launch.json` file

```
{"version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Python: Current File",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${file}",
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "justMyCode": true,
      "args": ["--experimentName", "Debugging"],
      "purpose": ["debug-in-terminal"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I was missing the 'purpose' key. After reading your comment, I added it and it worked.

Comment: FWIW in 2023 I couldn't get these arguments to pass correctly _until_ I used that esoteric "purpose" value in my launch.json

Comment: That's it! I spent hours following the docs to the T at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging to no avail until I came upon your solution. Thank you! Is this a recent thing in VS Code -- how come other "solutions" under this question don't need to do that?
Also, as @ingernet answered below, restarting VS Code (without adding that `purpose` attribute) also worked. This is got to be a bug in VS Code.

Comment: Also FWIW as of August 2023 this bug appears to have been fixed, at least for me running the latest VSCode.

Comment: Worked for me in Dec 2023...thank you!!

Answer (score 15):

```
--key1 value1 value2 --key2 value3 value4
```

can be passed as

```
"args": ["--key1=value1", "value2", "--key2=value3", "value4"]
```

<sub>(Combining the two answers by [Pawan Kumar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51244223/visual-studio-code-how-debug-python-script-with-arguments/51244649#51244649) and [Chunde Huang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51244223/visual-studio-code-how-debug-python-script-with-arguments/58941099#58941099).)</sub>

Answer (score 9):

In Visual Studio, you can pass multiple parameter as convenient and natural way:

```
--trail=0 --g=0 --V="HO" --save_interval=10 --verbose=True
```

I just do not know why they will not support this in Visual Studio Code. To list arguments one by one is cumbersome and a bit silly. They just pass the arguments string to the Python parser, and things can be done easily.

Comment: Your post is a comment, not an answer. You can consider moving it as a questions comment.

Answer (score 9):

File *launch.json* in the Python project folder path *.vscode*, tested in Visual Studio Code <kbd>F5</kbd>.

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "args": ["c", "pwd"],
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Nobody has mentioned this yet, so I thought I'd offer a suggestion that may save you some minutes and certainly some sanity. I set up my launch.json file with an `args` array, but I couldn't get my args to show up in the terminal when I ran the debugger.

All I had to do was quit and restart VS Code for some reason. Then it worked like a champ.

Comment: YES! Why didn't I try that trick before :-) It worked for me!

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget: Once you edit the launch.json file, CLICK OFF IT, back to the py file you want to debug, THEN hit the debug button! Otherwise, it will try to debug itself! (?)

Answer (score 1):

Combination of flags and arguments

`python3 program.py --flag1 --flag2 --arg1=value1 --arg2=value2`

launch.json:

`"args": ["--flag1", "--flag2", "--arg1", "value1", "--arg2", "value2"]`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the launch.json file is selected as the active debug configuration in Visual Studio Code, follow these steps:

1. Open the Visual Studio Code editor and navigate to the Debug view by clicking on the Debug icon in the left-hand sidebar or by pressing Ctrl+Shift+D (Windows/Linux) or Cmd+Shift+D (macOS).
2. In the Debug view, click on the “Run” button to start the debugger.
3. If you have multiple debug configurations defined in your launch.json file, you will be prompted to select the one you want to use. Select the appropriate configuration from the dropdown menu.
4. Once you have selected the debug configuration, the debugger will start and your code will be executed according to the settings in the launch.json file.