# VSCode python debug: "No module named xx" when using module attribute

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code, python-module

**My Python project folder structure is as follow**:

```
.python_practice
|--lib
    |--lib.py
    |--__init__.py
|--practice1
    |--my_module.py
    |--__init__.py
|--__init__.py
```

---

**My launch configuration is**

```
{
    "name": "Python: Module",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "module": "practice1.my_module",
    "console": "integratedTerminal"
 },
```

---

**In my_module.py**

```
from lib.lib import util_func
```

When I try to debug using VScode I get an error: `"No module named practice1.my_module"`

But when I run it with the following command it works fine

```
python -m practice1.my_module
```

How could I debug my code so that the relative import work?

Any help will be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 13):

You can try the following:

```json
{
    "name": "Python: A name example",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "practice1/my_module.py",
    "env": {
        "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}"
    },
}
```

- Using `program` instead of `module` is almost the same.
- You need to solve the `imports` as if you had the package installed. Therfore you need to add a `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: To find where to modfiy this, press ctrl+ shift + p and enter launch.json > click on 'Open launch.json'. Or just click on the cogwheel at the top of the run and debug side-bar. Or command pallette Run > Open Configurations.

Comment: Additionally, if your project is installable, you should be able to `pip install -e .` so that it is `--editable` but installed and your modules accesible.

Comment: for multiple `pythonpath`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41471578/visual-studio-code-how-to-add-multiple-paths-to-python-path , for `args` see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51244223/visual-studio-code-how-debug-python-script-with-arguments

Answer (score 5):

I have ran into the same issue. You may have two Python interpreters installed and only one has the modules you need. Try selecting another Python version by running from the command pallet (Ctl+Shift+p) then *python: Select Interpreter* and choose where your python lives. I had:

```
/usr/bin/python3
/usr/local/bin/python
```

Comment: This was it for me. I am also trying to debug inside a dev container...

Answer (score 3):

This is a [known bug](https://github.com/Microsoft/ptvsd/issues/991) involving debugging sub-modules.

Answer (score 2):

add env variable "PYTHONPATH" point to my app folder (where my app.py exist)
fixed my problem

```
{
      "name": "Python: Debugging App",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "app/app.py",
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "justMyCode": true,
      "env": {
        "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}/app"
      }
},
```