# ModuleNotFoundError when trying to debug a test

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, debugging, testing, python-unittest

I am trying to debug a failing test method in VS Code but when I use the `Debug Test` action from the Testing sidebar or the context menu for the test method, it fails with the following error (found in the Debug Console):

```
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_clients (unittest.loader._FailedTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError: Failed to import test module: test_clients
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/unittest/loader.py", line 154, in loadTestsFromName
    module = __import__(module_name)
  File "/home/melebius/git/my-project/my_project/tests/test_clients.py", line 9, in <module>
    from my_project.clients.base import Data
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_project'


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.007s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

The `my_project` folder is evidently not available to the Python interpreter. Unfortunately, I cannot find any information on where to define the path for a `Debug Test` run.

The ways I tried:

- I can `Debug Test` by [appending the path in my test file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60118494/711006) but I find this just a workaround because such a code should not be committed to Git.
- I can run “plain” debug (without involving `unittest`) using the `PYTHONPATH` configuration in my `.code-workspace` file.

  - This is the most common advice I have found ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53290328/cant-get-vscode-python-debugger-to-find-my-project-modules), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53323647/vscode-python-debug-no-module-named-xx-when-using-module-attribute)). I have multiple debug launch configurations (I don’t know *which* one is used by the `Debug Test` action) but have the `PYTHONPATH` in all of them.
- I  have defined `PYTHONPATH` in the `.env` file of my project.
- `Run Test` works well for my test method.
- I can run my tests in the command line (`python -m unittest`) from the project’s root directory. If I want to run them directly from the `tests` folder, I have to `export PYTHONPATH=/home/melebius/git/my-project` first.

Additional information:

- I use Python and Pylance extensions by Microsoft to provide the testing environment in VS Code.
- I use `venv` for my project which seems to be set up correctly. (I have resolved all `ModuleNotFoundError`’s for external libraries by running `pip install` in the `venv`.)
- I have multiple projects (folders) in my workspace and the debug launch configurations are currently set on the workspace level. I tried to create a `launch.json` file on the project level and put the `PYTHONPATH` there, too, but nothing changed. Workspace structure (simplified, showing just directories and mentioned files):

```
.
 |-my-project
 | |-my_project
 | | |-tests
 | | |-clients
 | | |-tools
 | |-.git
 | |-.vscode
 | | |-launch.json
 |-my-other-project
 | |-.git
 | |-...
 |-my-yet-another-project
 | |-.git
 | |-...
 |-my-projects.code-workspace
```

Where can I define the path for the `Debug Test` action in VS Code?

Comment: Can you provide your workspace directory structure and `launch.json`? By the way, will it show the same error when running python file instead of debugging? Is using method `sys. path()` feasible?

Comment: @MingJie-MSFT I’ve added some information to my question, including the directory structure. I am not sure what you mean by the feasibility of the `sys.path()` method. It works well when I put the `import sys` and `sys.path().append()` statements to my code but I am not satisfied with this as a permanent solution.

Comment: Can you set subdirectory `my_project` as the workspace? Your directory structure `launch.json` obviously won't work.

Comment: @MingJie-MSFT I am sorry this does not make sense in my case. The projects are interdependent and I find maintaining them in a single workspace helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by installing `my-project` in [editable mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35064498/711006) to my Python virtual environment.

```
pip install -e ./my-project
```