# Cannot get VS Code to pass arguments to Python from launch.json

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I cannot figure out how to get VS Code for Mac to start debugging my Python script with the arguments I have defined in my launch.json file by using the debug button to the right I have circled here. The only way I can get my arguments to be recognized is if I go to the menu and select "Run|Start Debugging" or if press F5.

How do I tell VS Code to use my launch.json file when using that button???

If you look at the answer from Sourya Dey at the link below, this is what made me write this. There must be some simple setting or step missing to link that button to F5. It appears others are also confused about this.

[Visual Studio Code: How debug Python script with arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51244223/visual-studio-code-how-debug-python-script-with-arguments)

[image: VS Code for Mac]

For clarity, here is my launch.json file which works as expected with F5. It does not work with the button I have circled in red above

[image: launch.json]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Update May 2022 from Microsoft tech support on github issues for vscode-python

You need to add this section to your launch.json file:
"purpose": ["debug-in-terminal"]

I just tested it on VS Code 1.67.1 and it works. The documentation appears to state that if you add this "flag" then F5 or Run > Debug won't use the launch.json settings but they do. I have asked them to update their docs to make this clearer as it is confusing.

============

I filed a bug with the Microsoft VS Code team regarding this issue and they sent me over to the Microsoft Python extension group. I then filed a bug there referencing the VC Code ticket and it was immediately assigned for "area-debugging triage". I presume this will be fixed in a later version (I am on 1.63.2)

First, it is not obvious where this button comes from. I have noted this issue as well with Microsoft so they can improve their documentation. When you install VS Code with no extensions, this button is not present. But as soon as you load your first Python file, Microsoft urges you to install the official "Microsoft Python Extension" and then the button shows up. In my mind, I assumed this was a native VS Code button that showed up when you had a language debugger installed. When I removed all extensions, except the Microsoft Python extension, I was convinced this was part of VS Code.

The answer above incorrectly states that this is the correct behaviour for the button. It is not. Microsoft has confirmed this and if you read issue #2338 ("Documentation for python.terminal.launchArgs is unclear") there is a response in there stating:

"Unfortunately that's just how vscode works. When debugging all settings are read from launch.json and non-debugging settings.json is used
This applies to all languages (extensions) in vscode."

So for now, there is nothing much to do other than wait for this to be fixed.

Lastly, for those who are wondering why I wanted to use that button in the first place. For the most part, I use keyboard mappings to start debugging when I am inside VS Code. But for this particular project, I was going to other external windows and when coming back to VS Code, since I was already using the mouse, I just wanted to click there out of convenience. I don't keep the debug tab open which also has a debug button that works as intended.

Comment: What an amazing and life saving response !

Comment: Thank you, I have checked it. The same issue is still in VSCode v1.78.2(Universal) on Mac M1. There also needs "purpose": ["debug-in-terminal"],