# debug with terminal commands in vscode

Tags: python, vscode-debugger

For some reason, I want to debug my python file in vscode via the command line.

I followed this guide. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging

The guide says that I can use this command

```
python -m debugpy --listen 5678 ./myscript.py
```

And then use the following configuration to attach from the VS Code Python extension.

```
{
  "name": "Python: Attach",
  "type": "python",
  "request": "attach",
  "connect": {
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 5678
  }
}
```

But I'm totally in the dark about how can I use this lauch.json configuration to attach the debugger.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio Code: How debug Python script with arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51244223/visual-studio-code-how-debug-python-script-with-arguments)

Comment: sorry, this is totally another question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this problem, after running the command line command, create a fresh new launch.json file, choose "remote attach", and vscode will pop up a prompt where you can enter host and port number. The debugger will automatically run for you after that!