# I met a question with of vscode debugging with arguments

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, debugging

recently i am started to learn python with debugging mode step by step, but i am stuck in `args = parser.parse_args()`  with error: `SystemExit:2`

```
import time
import torch
import numpy as np
from train_eval import train, init_network
from importlib import import_module
import argparse
from tensorboardX import SummaryWriter


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Chinese Text Classification')
parser.add_argument('--model', type=str, required=True, help='choose a model: TextCNN, TextRNN, FastText, TextRCNN, TextRNN_Att, DPCNN, Transformer')
parser.add_argument('--embedding', default='pre_trained', type=str, help='random or pre_trained')
parser.add_argument('--word', default=False, type=bool, help='True for word, False for char')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

i found it's caused running with no arg, so i edit the `launch.json` refrerred [Visual Studio Code: How debug Python script with arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51244223/visual-studio-code-how-debug-python-script-with-arguments)

but still error

and my code run normally when using command line like `python run.py --model TextRNN`
so i think it's caused by my debug settings, but i don't know how to fix it , could you please help me?

## My settings

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python_textRNN",
            "type": "python",
            "python": "D:\miniconda\envs\ML3.8\python.exe",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "showOutput": "always",
            "justMyCode": "true",
            "args": ["--model","TextRNN"],

        },
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be using the wrong debugging method. If you configured *launch.json* and want it to work, you need to use the green triangle button in the **Run and Debug** panel to start debugging.

[image]

Or use `Run --> Start Debugging/Run Without Debugging`,

[image]

But if you directly use `Debug Python File` under the triangle menu in the upper right corner of the code editing page, this will not refer to the configuration in *launch.json*.

[image]