# Visual Studio Code: How debug PHP script with arguments

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

[image]
There is this play button in VSCode that allows to either `Run PHP File` or `Debug PHP File`.
I'm wondering how I can configure that PHP is started with additional command line arguments, as I am debugging a CLI script. I can install the `PHP Debug` extension and create a `launch.json` file. When I add an `args` member to a certain section, I can run the command line using a different play button.

There is this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51244223/visual-studio-code-how-debug-python-script-with-arguments), here on Stackoverflow, that says the Python debug extension accepts a `purpose` member in the launch file to make the debugger consider command line arguments.

How can I use said button in PHP CLI development?

Comment: php uses xdebug for debugging. it has to be installed on the server and configured in vs code

Answer (score 0):

You kinda answered your own question, use the `launch.json` file to configure the command which is executed when you press the "run and debug" button, the options are extension specific in you case [PHP Debug](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=xdebug.php-debug#supported-launch.json-settings) description have list of supported options and there is section "Options specific to CLI debugging", you either look for `args` (script args) or `runtimeArgs` (php binary args) option.

The `purpose` option is **not** available for PHP. For python you have another "run" button, it mimics the "run and debug" button but there was/is bug which ignored the config for "run" button, which the `purpose` config option solve, but restarting VSCode solve it too.

You didn't said specifically what your issue is, looks like you provide args and they are not observed somewhere, you might have issue down the line. Provide more info like your launch.json config and output of debug console.